# Java Wurfl Implementation Exception

Tags: java, spring, wurfl

I am getting following error and please help me where I am doing wrong

```
ERROR n.s.wurfl.core.GeneralWURFLEngine - cannot initialize: java.lang.NullPointerException: in is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: in is null
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.<init>(ZipInputStream.java:100) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.<init>(ZipInputStream.java:79) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
    at net.sourceforge.wurfl.core.resource.FileLoader.fromZipFile(FileLoader.java:248) ~[wurfl-1.5.jar:na]
    at net.sourceforge.wurfl.core.resource.FileLoader.openInputStream(FileLoader.java:230) ~[wurfl-1.5.jar:na]
```

wurfl.zip is inside /web-inf/  and my spring configuration for wurfl is below

```
    <bean id="net.sourceforge.wurfl.core.WURFLEngine" class="net.sourceforge.wurfl.core.GeneralWURFLEngine">        
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="classpath:/wurfl.zip" />
    <property name="engineTarget" value="performance" />
```

Code which is implementing above is

```
WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request.getSession().getServletContext());
WURFLEngine holder = (WURFLEngine)wac.getBean(WURFLEngine.class.getName());
System.out.println("debugging request: "+request+"  ==wurflholder: "+holder+ " Holder String "+holder.toString());
```

Output displayed:

```
debugging request: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@133b7e9
==wurflholder: net.sourceforge.wurfl.core.GeneralWURFLEngine@6f28c4 
==Holder: String net.sourceforge.wurfl.core.GeneralWURFLEngine@6f28c4
```

But It is giving error on the following code

```
try{
    device = holder.getDeviceForRequest(request); //This is giving exception 

    }
    catch(Exception e ){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/web-inf/` directory is not in the classpath, which is causing the exception to be thrown.

Try placing your `wurfl.zip` in `/web-inf/classes` for it to be loaded properly.

Comment: Yeah I did that and boom! it ran. I visited to post Answer myself but you already did it!  cheers.